# ASP.NET Identity with External Login using OpenIdConnect (O365) - Cannot get claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET Identity with External Login using OpenIdConnect (O365). I have registered the app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and delegated permissions. The flow of the app is like this:

1. Unregistered user logs in using OpenId
2. User is prompted to register (Working till here)
3. The Email address used to sign-in to O365 should be displayed in a TextBox which will be read-only when the user is asked to register. (Not Working)

The problem here is that the variable email is always null. I have included User.Read and Email in my scope, but it seems like it does not return these.

How do I get email to be populated with the same email address the user used to sign in to O365?

Code as below:

**Statup.Auth.cs**

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
              new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
              {
                  Authority = "https://login.microsoft.com/common/v2.0",
                  ClientId = "clientId",
                  ClientSecret = "clientSecret",
                  Scope = "openid User.Read email offline_access",
                  RedirectUri = "redirectUri",
                  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                  {
                      ValidateIssuer = false,
                  }
```

**Controller - /Account/ExternalLoginCallback**

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    var email = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email);
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok...so I nailed it. This was the problem:

Modified as below:

```
Scope = "openid profile email offline_access"
```

and for the Email we have to use `preferred_username`